# How does helium 2 at superfluidity occupy the same quantum state

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

As my question states, at 2K and below, helium 2 is a superfluid that apparently can defy the laws of entropy.  This is explained that at this temperature, all atoms are in the same quantum state.  Doesn't this violate the exclusion principle?

Comment: 3, not 2 I think….

Comment: You are thinking of the Pauli exclusion principle no?

Comment: (1) While helium has atomic number 2, its two stable isotopes are helium-3 and helium-4. Both have a superfluid phase. (2) The transition to a zero-entropy fluid phase does not violate the laws of entropy; if this is your question, please [edit] to clarify. (3) You seem to have written "uncertainty principle" instead of "exclusion principle." The exclusion principle doesn't apply to bosons like helium-4; the mechanism of superfluidity in fermionic helium-3 is a nontrivial question.

Answer (score 0):

The atoms form pairs which have a integer spin.The pairs  then obey the Bose-Einstein statistics.Superconductivitity is also very similar to superfluidity with the difference that instead of groups of atoms we have groups of electrons.